# Script to generate checksums for new files only?

Tags: windows, batch-file, checksum, md5sum

I’ve created (well, lifted) a script for powershell to monitor a folder for new files, when new files are added it runs the following batch file to generate checksums:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do md5sum "%%a" >> "%%a.md5"
```

Files are regularly being added to the folder so I only want the script to run on the new files.  At the moment it runs from scratch each time generating checksums for the same file over and over.  I tried an IF NOT EXIST statement but this only checks the folder for a single instant:

```
if not exist "*.txt.md5" (for %%a in (*.txt) do md5sum "%%a" >> "%%a.md5")
```

I presume I need to scan the folder, generate a list of files and then skip over the ones that have checksums?  This is where it goes a bit over my head - can anyone advise?

One thing to note - it’s important each file has a separate checksum (e.g. File.txt - File.txt.md5) opposed to generated in a single list, as the files go their separate ways.

Thank you!

Comment: wrong logic. `for %%a in (*.txt) do if not exist "%%a.md5" md5sum "%%a" >> "%%a.md5"`

Comment: That was far simpler than I expected - works great!  Thank you.